# How to split a string by a specific pattern in number of characters?

Tags: python

I am working on a sensor which gives a burst of 1000 readings in hex at a time.

The resulting response of the sensor is something like below - 
4024f003503140402510033031204024f0038030d04024f0036030a04024e0039030c040254003

I have to split this first into 14 characters, so for example, one reading is 4024f003503140, further need to split it as [40,24f0,0350,3140] and drop 40 from each of the list, finally getting the output [24f0,0350,3140]

I tried to look for the solution and most of the answers where by a kind of for loop, but mostly they were of similar character length.
Any neat way pull this off?

Comment: and what have you tried so far, sir ?

Comment: How do you know the reading is `4024f003503140` ? Is every reading fixed length?

Comment: ...and on what basis did you split that reading?

Comment: I'm quite stuck in the first step itself.  Well, if it was the string to be split in same nos of characters, it was easier to have it done thorugh a for loop.  But, in this case, I have no idea to approach to the solution.

Comment: the sensor can also provide a single reading at a time.  Therefore, I know for sure about its length and split pattern.  Every reading is of the fixed length, each starting with 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want a list of lists, and that the list is 14,000 characters long, and there won't be any errors like missing or spurious characters to worry about.

So a nested list comprehension will do this job. In this example I've shortened your sample input by 8 characters to make it evenly divisible by 14. This assumes perfect input data and doesn't check anything.

```
l = "4024f003503140402510033031204024f0038030d04024f0036030a04024e0039030c0"
print([[s[2:6], s[6:10], s[10:14]] for s in [l[m:m+14] for m in range(0, len(l), 14)]])
```

Result

```
[['24f0', '0350', '3140'], ['2510', '0330', '3120'], ['24f0', '0380', '30d0'], ['24f0', '0360', '30a0'], ['24e0', '0390', '30c0']]
```

Another approach is to use a generator function. This function will return a single list derived from each set of 14 characters. It is more memory-efficient although for 14K characters that is not a real issue, but it does allow for easier error checking, as shown in the `assert` statements. The result is identical.

```
l = "4024f003503140402510033031204024f0038030d04024f0036030a04024e0039030c0"
def sensor(l):
    assert len(l) % 14 == 0, f"Input length of {len(l)} is not a multiple of 14"
    for m in range(0, len(l), 14):
        s = l[m:m+14]
        assert s[:2] == "40", f"Missing Ack at position {m}"
        yield [s[:4], s[4:8], s[8:12]]

sensor_list = [s for s in sensor(l)]

print(sensor_list)
```

Comment: I added another approach that has some advantages when there's less certainty about the integrity of the input. It would be easier to customize as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for:

```
sensor_input = "4024f003503140"
values = [sensor_input[:2], sensor_input[2:6],sensor_input[6:10], sensor_input[10:14]]
print(values)
```

This gives you:

> ['40', '24f0', '0350', '3140']

If you add:

```
res = values[1:]
print (res)
```

Then you drop the '40' in the beginning, resulting in:

> ['24f0', '0350', '3140']

Comment: Be careful using built-in names as variable names. There you override `input()` function.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching and reached a roundabout answer..

```
import re
temp1 = re.findall('.{1,14}',temp)

for i,j in enumerate(temp1):
    temp1[i] = re.findall('.{1,4}',j[2:])
print(temp1)
```

Thanks everyone for the reply..@Deepstop Your code is brilliant one.. It will take sometime for me to comprehend it though..

Comment: I think your answer is pretty good too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help (z refers to the string generated by the sensor)

```
result = [x[2:] for x in re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}",z)]
```